# Why does PASTE mode mess up my text sometimes?

Tags: macos, paste

If I go to [this web page](https://git.aweirdimagination.net/perelman/fear_tracker/raw/commit/1c442bec41ca5c07dcf9a7f9a1599ef805568ee9/fear_tracker/routing.py) on my MacOS, hit Command+A to highlight all the text, Command+C to copy it, open vim, enter insert mode, and paste with Command+V, it looks like:

[image]

If I do exactly the same thing, but before pasting, I enter paste mode (`:set paste`), then enter insert mode, and paste, I get this:

[image]

At first I thought it was something in my .vimrc, so I commented out EVERYTHING in my .vimrc file, and it still happens. The screenshots are with a blank .vimrc file.

What's going on? Why is a mode specifically designed for pasting doing a worse job than regular mode?

Update: Upon further investigation, I realized that this only happens in neovim. vim works fine in both regular, and paste mode.

Update 2: On my MacOS, this seems to only happen when I'm SSHed into a Linux system using the MacOS Terminal app, where neovim is running. If I use the neovim that's on my MacOS (also with the Terminal app), it doesn't happen.

Comment: Er, `set paste` is supposed to avoid this. That's odd. What about `vim --clean` or `vim -u NONE`? Those can be technically different from a blank vimrc.

Comment: Might also try running vim with `--clean`...that ensures a known/sane configuration. Are you sure the text is clean before Vim gets a hold of it? One test would be to do `cat > /dev/null` from a shell command line see what it looks like pasted there. (Ctrl-C afterwards to quit.)  Certainly the source is clean but maybe your OS is doing something strange.

Comment: Sorry - just realized that this is happening in neovim - not vim. vim seems to work fine in both regular, and paste mode. Neovim doesn't have a `--clean` arg (which is how I realized I was using it), but does seem to support the `-u NONE` args, but those didn't help. Doing `cat > /dev/null` and pasting, it looks fine.

Comment: Yikes. Are you using nvim in a terminal emulator or a standalone GUI window? I don't know Macs well so not even sure there's such a choice. For that matter probably best if I defer to Mac people.

Comment: @BLayer On my MacOS, I have the built-in "Terminal" open. I'm using it to SSH into a Linux system, where neovim is running. I just tried it without SSHing into the Linux system - just neovim on my MacOS, and it doesn't happen. This might explain why I had such a hard time initially replicating the issue. Sometimes it happened, and sometimes it didn't. It appears to only happen under very specific conditions. I just happen to match those conditions quite frequently

Comment: Aha. I wouldn't be surprised then if it's like one switch/flag in the terminal emulator settings but like I said I'm Mac-less so 'fraid I won't be able to help with that. Take a look at the settings and  see if there's anything about tab stops, control characters, encoding ... things like that that seem...well..."wrong". :)

Comment: When you paste... Are those tabs? Can you try to use `:set list` to see if it's inserting tabs? It would be good to see if the clipboard on your Mac actually have tabs for those... It doesn't look like the original page has tabs, but perhaps when you're copying from your browser it's getting translated to that?

Comment: NeoVim `:help 'paste'` also says: *"This option is obsolete; bracketed-paste-mode is built-in."* So perhaps it's forcing you into bracketed-paste-mode and that's creating some interference somehow?

Comment: For that matter is it an up-to-date version of nvim? Don't know if you own the box or not but I've SSH'd into countless unfamiliar machines...mostly as part of work...and wildly out-of-date is the norm. (Hacker's paradise.) :)

Comment: @filbranden No - the super long lines are definitely spaces - not tabs. Not sure what bracketed-paste-mode is, or how to enable/disable that. it's a CentOS 7 box. Neovim 0.3.8. Pretty sure that's the latest one in the yum repos, but CentOS being CentOS, it's probably still an older version. For the record, using Windows to SSH into the same Linux machine, exactly the opposite happens. Pasting into regular mode messes it up exactly like in my screenshot, while pasting in PASTE mode works fine. Basically exactly as expected.